# Android Studio - Problema al reproducir audio

Tags: android-studio, archivo, sonido

Buenas.
Estoy haciendo una prueba sencilla en la que pulso un botón y se reproduce un sonido. Al emular la aplicación (o usándola en el móvil) y clickar el botón, la app se peta y se cierra. Creo que el problema es que no encuentra el archivo de audio, porque tengo otro método en el que reproduzco un sonido que grabo y no me da ningún problema, puesto que ese audio lo crea la propia app y sé donde está. El código es este:

Definición del botón en XML

```
public void soundTest (View view) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); 
        mediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Fallo en reproducción");
        }
    }
```

La función a la que llama el botón

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/sound"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sound"
        android:onClick="soundTest"/>
```

He creade la carpeta raw correctametne y el archivo test.mp3 está en ella. No me lanza ningún error

Comment: Trata siempre de buscar en el LogCat para encontrar el problema rápidamente.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso, no debes usar `prepare()` y posteriormente `start()` o viceversa:

```
mediaPlayer.prepare();
 mediaPlayer.start();
```

Debes usar el listener `OnPreparedListener()` para determinar cuando el MediaPlayer esta listo para reproducción y de esta forma llamar el método `start()` para iniciar la reproducción:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        //Inicia reproducción.
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

---

El código completo sería:

```
public void soundTest (View view) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); 
        mediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
        try {
              mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
              @Override
              public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                  //Inicia reproducción.
                  mediaPlayer.start();
              }
          });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Fallo en reproducción");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No instancies la clase MediaPlayer, usa esta declaración de una linea que te voy a poner.

Supongo que tienes una variable de clase declarada en tu zona de variables tal que asi:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```

Borrala y Prueba esto en tu metodo, deberia funcionar:

```
public void soundTest (View view) {
      MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
      try {
          mediaPlayer.prepare();
          mediaPlayer.start();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Fallo en reproducción");
      }
 }
```